# URL breaking when it contains # in jQuery ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I request a url with jquery Ajax that contains # sign, the string of the url after # gets cut off. For example:

```
http://somesitem.com/?name=Some#thing
```

When I observe this url being requested in firebug, I see that all that is being submitted is:

```
http://somesitem.com/?name=Some
```

I tried to use encodeURI function with no success.

Any tips on how to submit the entire string containing the #?

Answer (score 2):

encodeURI does not remove "#". You'll need to use encodeURIComponent

```
encodeURIComponent('Some#thing')
```

This should produce something like this:

```
Some%23thing
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing '#' with '%23'.  .

Comment: None of the other solutions work. This works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the `#` character has a special meaning. It's basically a reserved character. I'd probably just suggest you use a different character for whatever you're using it for.

Answer (score 0):

The fragment identifier is never passed to the server. If you want to send it to the server you'd need to first convert the existing fragment to a standard url parameter.

```
var url = window.location;
//url = http://somesitem.com/?name=Some
url += '&hash='+window.location.hash;
//url = http://somesitem.com/?name=Some&hash=thing
$.get(url);
```

> The fragment identifier functions differently than the rest of the
>   URI: namely, **its processing is exclusively client-side with no
>   participation from the server** — of course the server typically helps
>   to determine the MIME type, and the MIME type determines the
>   processing of fragments. **When an agent (such as a Web browser)
>   requests a resource from a Web server, the agent sends the URI to the
>   server, but does not send the fragment**. Instead, the agent waits for
>   the server to send the resource, and then the agent processes the
>   resource according to the document type and fragment value

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Special characters in JQuery documentation include #

It says use two \ to escape in JQuery (I believe only once in javascript).